# Regex match all text after dash

Tags: java, regex

I try to get all text after hyphen (dash). For example, if I have a text like this:

```
123-text
```

I need to get `text`.

I tried this:

```
^.*(?=(\-))
```

But it matches all text after dash with that dash and I need to get just text.

Comment: Maybe all you need is remove the `^[^-]*-` match? What is the programming environment?

Comment: Enviroment is java, but anyway thank you it works. Add it like answer and will mark your answer and give you +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all text before the first occurrence of a hyphen and the hyphen(s) right after with

```java
String result = text.replaceFirst("^[^-]*-+", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9aOQn4/1). The `replaceFirst` will find and remove the first occurrence of

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-`
- `-+` - one or more `-` chars.

An approach with `String#split` is also viable:

```java
String text = "123-text";
String[] chunks = text.split("-", 2);        // limit splitting into 2 chunks
System.out.println(chunks[chunks.length-1]); // Get the last item
// => text
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/jIC6NT).